# Redirecting Outlook Meeting Request

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013, calendar

I'm using `Microsoft Outlook 2013` with two e-mail addresses:
A `hotmail` one and a non-hotmail one. Whenever I receive a meeting request, it is sent to my non-hotmail one. That is tedious since I need to copy the entry from my local calendar into my hotmail calendar so that it is synchronized with my phone and laptop. Consider the non-hotmail address as my company contact. Then I also delete the duplicate from the local calendar so that I don't get 2 notifications on my laptop when the date has been reached. Also if it gets updated I need to do the copying and deleting again.

Is there a way to make meeting requests to be registered on my hotmail calendar in Outlook instead of the local one? Basically by redirecting all meeting requests sent to me to my hotmail e-mail address instead so that it seems like it was sent to my hotmail in the first place?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just make the hotmail calendar the default calendar? Or to keep them synced to one another? Also, look into the [outlook connector](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-an-Outlookcom-account-in-Outlook-a8ad4824-c286-43bb-8103-12a73cf2c954?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Comment: @Raystafarian: That doesn't work
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-outlook/default-calendar-in-outlook-2013/a6926c77-a361-42da-8575-6605057f12a1

Comment: Change the default PST, easy. Otherwise, you're looking for something with 2-way sync, which will be a software recommendation. Unfortunately, outlook isn't easy to work with in this regard.